# Is virtualbox shared folder working for Debian guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, debian, shared-folders

This is very strange. I'm running Debian and Ubuntu guests under the same virtualbox (hosted under Win7). And the Debian and Ubuntu mostly have the same packages installed. And I did the same steps to install guest additions. All went on fine.

Just that under my Ubuntu (Saucy), I can see the shared folder mount, but under my Debian (Sid), the shared folder mount is not there.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: How are you mounting them? Are you using a command or is it done automatically? Have you tried `mount -t vboxfs share mountpoint`?

Comment: Ah, yes, that leads to my discovery that my Debian guest addition was not installed properly. Please answer so that I can accept.

Comment: Here you go, feel free to edit my answer to include more details on what exactly you had to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the guest additions are installed correctly for both guest OSes and that the share is correctly mounted. You should be able to mount using

```
mount -t vboxfs share mountpoint
```